# Removing the code signature from a mac app executable

Tags: objective-c, macos, assembly

I have a signed mac app executable. I initialised `NSMutableData` with the content of code signed executable. Then I modified some part of the executable and I saved the modified executable. When I tried the run the original app with this modified executable, the app crashed.

Crash log is,

```
 System Integrity Protection: disabled

 Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

 Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
 Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
 Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

 Termination Reason:    Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x2
```

From the crash log it is clear that it crashed because of invalid code signature. 
I don't have source code for the app and I'm simply trying to fix some bugs in someone's old app.

So my question is how to remove code signature of a binary in objective c ?

Comment: The whole point of code signing is to make something like this impossible. It's a way to verify that an app has not been tampered with.

Comment: @ItaiFerber My aim is not to distribute this app in app store. In Hopper disassembler we can remove code signature from an executable and save it as a new executable. So how to do that in objective-c ?

Comment: What's your actual goal here?

Comment: Now when I run modified executable without removing code signature the app seems to be crashing. So my aim is to remove code signature so that my app won't crash.

Comment: if its your app, just compile/build it without codesign. If its not - hands off - as you will most probably violate rights.

Comment: Sounds like he want to pirate the app and release in Cydia store. Glad it can't work out.

Comment: I'm a security researcher. So I have a old mac app which has some undesired behavior and I wanted to remove it. So I disassembled the app and found some bad assembly instructions. So I modified them. Now so as to make the app to work i have to remove the code signature. So enough with advices.

Comment: @genecode first read the question it is related to mac not ios. So don't comment if you are not asking something useful.

Comment: Down voters what is exactly wrong in the question ? Kindly explain.

Comment: What were the "bad assembly instructions"? Never heard of such a thing...

Comment: What I meant was some unwanted assembly instructions. For more information about mac app read my detailed question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858288/creating-a-software-patcher-in-mac/44860138?noredirect=1#comment76708935_44860138

Comment: Are you meaning the part that is supposed to license or register it? — specifically, what are the assembly instructions you are patching. If you remove the code signature the app won't run unless the user turns off their gatekeeper settings.

Comment: Take that part as what ever you want and it is irrelevant to the question. Since question is all about removing code signature and not about patching the existing binary. Yep I know if code signature is removed then gatekeeper will complain about that. I will take care of that. Again how to remove the code signature from a signed executable ?

Comment: It is relevant, because you linked your other question about patching to this one. Also, some binaries will not run with the code signature stripped; you answered your question, below — did your answer not work?

Comment: My answer works sometimes and it is not reliable. This is the thing my organization has an note taking app where we can set password to the app as well as individual notes. I tried to bypass password validation and I successfully did it in my Mac(by modifying assembly instructions) . As I want to show this to everyone in my organization I thought of building a patcher. I'm sure that this binary will run with code signature stripped ( since I used hopper, modified assembly instructions and stripped code signature and it ran perfectly).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148194/discussion-between-jaffer-sheriff-and-lll).

Comment: @ItaiFerber Code signatures were once meant to protect the user from apps that maliciously had been tampered with, not to take away the rights of a user to use his device any way he desires.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For all moral preachers, thanks for enlighting my life and showing the moral path of life.

It's not well documented at all, from what I can tell, but you may be able to remove code signing via:

```
      codesign --remove-signature appName
```

Alternate Way :

Patching up decrypted files (removing LC_CODE_SIGNATURE)
——————————————————————————————

Make sure you have got the files thinned (ditto --arch i386) before proceeding.

To remove a code signature you need to do the following steps:
NOTE: Intel Mach-O binaries start with 0xCEFAEDFE
             PPC Mach-O binaries start with 0xFEEDFACE

1. - Modify the number of load commands (Starts at offset 0x10/16, 4B size).
   - If the load commands are e.g. 0x2C subtract 0x1 -> 0x2B.
2. - Modify the size of the load commands (Starts at offset 0x14/20, 4B size).
   - remember for Intel you need to swap the bytes to get the value...
     If it reads as FC 17 00 00 it actually is 0x000017FC
   - Subtract 0x10 or 16 from the value. in the case above -> 0x000017EC
   - swap bytes again (for Intel). 0x000017EC is thus EC 17 00 00
3. - Modify the 16 Bytes from the load command entry for LC_CODE_SIGNATURE.
     Replace them with 16 x 0x00.
     This entry starts with 0x1D000000 on Intel and 0x0000001D on PPC.
   - This modifies the load command (8B) and the contents of the load command (8B).
     In this case the load command in total should allways be:
     Intel: 0x1D00000010000000
     PPC: 0x0000001D00000010
4. - Remove the actual code signature.
     This starts with 0xFADE0CC0 on both Intel and PPC.
     Replace the entire code signature with 0x00 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to decrementing `Mach_header.ncmds` and reducing `Mach_header.sizeofcmds`, in my case `codesign --remove-signature` also truncated the file, removing the data portion of the signature, and also removing of 8 bytes of zero padding which followed the string text belonging to LC_SYMTAB (the data portion of LC_CODE_SIGNATURE must be 16-byte aligned.)  This also reduced the `__LINKEDIT.filesize` so that it marked the position of end-of-file.